# query mediastore for newly added files and recently changed ones

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager, android-music-player, android-mediascanner

I am making a music player app in android.When app starts ,I query all the songs in mediastore ,and show them in list.I also have options to edit information and deleting them from phone.I want to refresh my list .What are some ways to refresh list?

As doing query again would be time consuming if there are a lot of songs.

How do i know if media store has been changed or some audio files have been recently added? So that i get only those files.

> How can I detect the change of mediastore when I delete or add a mp3 file from or to the sdcard.

Comment: are you using content provider ?

Comment: yes.I access files using content resolver ,and get cursor as returned value .

Answer (score 0):

For Cursor cursor = getContentRevolver().query(Uri, query, selection,args,order);
The cursor.getCount(); returns an integer number of all available songs on device. Get this number and save it with sharedpreferences. Check that this number has not changed everytime you launch your activity. If else, update the library.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: what if user deleted 1 song and downloaded another song?